# Drone CI "Error: missing Docker image"

Tags: drone.io

I'm hosting my own Drone instance. My `.drone.yml` is as follows:

```
build:
  image: node:latest
  commands:
    - npm install
    - npm run compile
```

However, whenever it runs it spits out the error:

```
Error: missing Docker image
```

with no context whatsoever. What could possibly be going wrong this early in the build?

Comment: I am not familiar with drone.  But if the parent docker image is actually missing, it won't begin building.  Does running "docker image" on the command prompt reveal the list of docker images in your setup?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I resolved it updating the drone version. It seems that the 0.3 doesn't support build:

You can use the following syntax:

```
image: node:latest
script:
 - npm install
 - npm run compile
```

I highly recommend to use the latest version.